# Can this be expressed using ALCQ syntax?

Tags: semantic-web, description-logic

Is it valid, using ALCQ, to write:

```
likes ≡ ¬dislikes   
¬∃(Dog ⊓ dislikes.(Colourful ⊓ Toy))
```

in order to express that every dog likes the colourful toys?

Also, is it valid to write:

```
Cute(∀Pomeranian)
```

in order to express that every pomeranian is cute?

Comment: Why do you use the negation in the 2nd line of ALCQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, formula `likes ≡ ¬dislikes` doesn't belong to ALCQ because it's missing role hierarchies (H in its name).

if you don't have to use `dislike` explicitly:

```
Dog ⊑ ∃likes.(Colourful ⊓ Toy)
```

then `Cute(∀Pomeranian)` is not a valid ALCQ formula, instead simply use:

```
Pomeranian ⊑ Cute
```